# how to extract files form a jar file?

Tags: jar, extract

i tried to extract files from a jar file. But it showed me an error in the command prompt. the error is "could not create directory"

i tried following command to extract jar file in command prompt.

jar xf jar_filename

Comment: what about your permissions in the folder where you executed this command ?

Answer (score 0):

Use WinRar to extract a .jar file. Right-click th jar to extract and choose extract files. Now specify the directory where you have write permission. For example d:\ instead of c:\

Answer (score 0):

use winzip or winrar and simply unzip it..